# Correct use of all/both

Tags: nouns

Are the sentences;

“He broke both his legs”
And
“He broke all his legs”

Both technically correct?

Comment: _All_ is only appropriate if 'he' belongs to a species with more than two!

Comment: @KateBunting Or Jake the Peg? Sorry we don't mention Rolf Harris any more, do we?

Comment: _Both_ is a suppletive dual form that **means** _all two_. It has to be used instead of _all_ when pairs are being summed.

Comment: IMHO, "all" is technically correct, but not idiomatic.